# Conventions for memory management and destructors / free() with Python's CFFI?

Tags: python, python-cffi

If I'm wrapping a C class:

```
from ._ffi import ffi, lib

class MyClass(object):
     def __init__(self):
         self._c_class = lib.MyClass_create()
```

What are best practices for making sure that `lib.MyClass_destroy(…)` is called?

Does `cffi` have some sort of wrapper around objects that will call a destructor when the Python object is GC'd, for example something like:

```
my_obj = managed(lib.MyClass_create(), destructor=lib.MyClass_destroy)
```

Or should that destructor logic be in the class's `__del__`? Something like:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __del__(self):
        if self._c_class is not None:
            lib.MyClass_destroy(self._c_class)
```

What are the best practices here?

Comment: Both are possible.  ("managed"() is "ffi.gc()".)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `ffi.gc()` is the way to go. This is the small wrapper I've written which also does the post-malloc `NULL` check:

```
def managed(create, args, free):
    o = create(*args)
    if o == ffi.NULL:
        raise MemoryError("%s could not allocate memory" %(create.__name__, ))
    return ffi.gc(o, free)
```

For example:

```
c_class = managed(lib.MyClass_create, ("some_arg", 42),
                  lib.MyClass_destroy)
```